# maximum occurance of an element in an array in tcl

Tags: arrays, tcl, proc

I have an array as follows

array = { a a a a b b b c c c c c c}

in the above array "a" is accured 4 times , b is 3 times , c as 6 times

could you help me with  the proc to get the output as 6 if my input is above array

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using a [dict](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/dict.htm)ionary to hold the count of each element, then the [`max`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/mathfunc.htm#M25) function to get the maximum value.

```
set array { a a a a b b b c c c c c c}
foreach elem $array {dict incr count $elem}
set max [tcl::mathfunc::max {*}[dict values $count]]
puts $max   ; # => 6
```

The "splat" ([`{*}`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/Tcl.htm#M9)) expands a list of values into its individual elements to feed into the `max` function.